# Is it possible to change the color of the disabled button to the same color as the background stackpanel?

Tags: uwp

Is it possible to change the color of the disabled button to the same color as the background stack panel?

[image]

I try several ways and still can not make it works

Your comment welcome

Comment: the new answer works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the color of the disabled button to the same color as the background stackpanel?

For this scenario, you could check button's style and find `ButtonBackgroundDisabled` StaticResource, if we set button disable, the button will load `ButtonBackgroundDisabled` color.

So, we just need to make a **ButtonBackgroundDisabled** `SolidColorBrush` same as stackpanel like the following.

```
<Page.Resources>   
    <Color x:Key="PanelBackground">#F0F078D0</Color>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" Color="{StaticResource PanelBackground}" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{StaticResource PanelBackground}">
    <Button
        VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False" 
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="Click"
        Visibility="Visible" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Button x:Name="stopButton_" Background="#D3D3D3" BorderThickness="0.3" BorderBrush="Black" IsEnabled="False" Height="48" Width="96" Margin="5.5">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
              CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#D3D3D3" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>

                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </ContentPresenter>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Change the background in the "Disabled" `VisualState`.